# Picture inside centered div shifted a bit

Tags: html, css

I need to display a logo in the middle of a header, so I put it inside a div with following properties:

```
header {
    background:#840CFF;
    width:100%;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

div.logo-main{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

But log is actually shifted a bit to the left. Why?

UPD: HTML code:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <div class = "logo-main">
            <img src="logo_forest.png">
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add html code.

Comment: If you dont share/post anything , how would we know why what shifted & why?

Comment: How do we know where the logo should be? Screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding on the left and right. Use `padding: 30px 0` instead of `padding: 30px`

```css
header {
  background: #840CFF;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
div.logo-main {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo-main">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Without viewing the problem(screenshot as such) , how you are able to know the solution . And if you provided the right solution as wanted by the OP than its commendable !

Comment: And why did padding do this? If the padding was the same on the left and the right, wouldn't it cancel each other out?

Comment: No, it doesn't cancel but overflows. @n01ze You can write the HTML and  view the output by his provided CSS. It is easy to find out. Overflow occurred and scroll bar is visible.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different methods in which to achieve this.

The method you're trying to do seems to be the simple `text-align` method.
Which makes an element 'flow' with the text and center itself in the middle.

The other is a little complicated (well I did when I first started using this method). You want to make the element have 'automatic' margins so that it positions itself in the center. Here's the simple method first

```
header{width:100%;padding:0;text-align:center;/*remove your 30px padding. It's what's causing the positioning error*/}
.logo-main{display:inline-block;}
```

Now for the slightly more complicated method :

```
header{position:relative;width:/*not sure you need to set a block element 100%?*/}
.logo-main{position:absolute;top:30px;/*what you set with padding*/left:0;right:0;margin:0px;auto;}
```

But back to the reason why you have a position error is because you're setting header at 100%. Then adding 30px to all sides. so that's 100% + (30px + 30px) meaning header would probably actually be larger than it's parent container by 60px. Making your `.logo-main` off center by 30px.